# What does ProvideWindowInsets means?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to learn Jetpack Compose, in the JetChat application I have found the following code, however I don't understand what it does exactly.

```
ProvideWindowInsets(consumeWindowInsets = false).
```

Comment: You can find everything about it in official docs: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

Comment: Ah gotta love Android development... that library is now deprecated without any replacement for ProvideWindowInsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProvideWindowInsets() {} means you can access the window inset values with LocalWindowInsets.current in any of the child compose functions inside ProvideWindowInsets() {}.

With consumeWindowInsets = false, the window insect values keep passing down the view hierarchy. For a visual explanation, check out Chris Banes's slides, https://chris.banes.dev/becoming-a-master-window-fitter-lon/ .  Look for the slides near the end, "WindowInsets will be passed down until it has been consumed".